# Dynamically created <div> won't position properly

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a web app that utilizes two `textareas`, and when a button is clicked one of the `textareas` is replaced with a `div` using JavaScript. I am trying to get the `div` inserted onto the page in the exact position as its `textarea` predecessor so the user doesn't notice the switch, but for some reason it's not as easy as it should be. The vertical position of the div seems to change based on the content within it. I have a feeling it has to do with

```
display: inline-block;
```

in my CSS file, but that's needed to keep the two `textareas` horizontally centered without a fixed width.

Any help would be appreciated.

The web app can be found on my site: http://lobian.co/code/remove-attributes/. To view the problem, input any amount of text in the left `textarea` then click "Remove Attributes". The `div` in question will replace the `textarea`.

**UPDATE:**
Musa's answer below fixed the problem.

Comment: Set the div to the same display mode?

Comment: You need to explicitly set the height of the div.

Comment: @TheZ it does have the same display mode - both the `textareas` and `div` have `inline-block`.

Comment: @Tom the `div` does have an explicit height of 100%. But Musa's answer below seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I can't see any problem in Chrome, unless you just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give both elements the same vertical-alignment, eg `vertical-align:top`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9GXJF/)

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks Musa! Just verifying before marking as correct.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
div#color_change {
    padding: 0;
}
```

You are giving 2px padding of div(44% width) which increases its size.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. I removed the padding and the problem still occurs.

Comment: My mistake, I've been working in Chrome. Your solution does help, but I think Musa addressed the underlying issue. But upvote for the help.